# How to get connection information for broken socket?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm getting an errno 104 - ECONNRESET Connection reset by peer from a `recv` call.  For debugging purposes I'd like to know what the other end of the connection was, and I'm using [`getpeername()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xns/getpeername.html) to do that.  But that call is failing with errno 107 - ENOTCONN Transport endpoint is not connected.  So it appears that once the connection is lost, the information is irretrievable.  Is there an alternate way to get the data about the remote end of the socket?

I know I could keep my own table of open sockets and their associated connection information, but that's not easy to do in the code base I'm working with.

Comment: *"Is there an alternate way to get the data about the remote end of the socket?"* - No, because if the socket is closed there is no connection anymore associated with the socket and thus no remote end to retrieve from it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich but the local socket hasn't been explicitly closed yet.  It's closed in the sense that there's no longer an open connection, but the socket number still has some meaning to the OS and the OS should retain some information.  I had hoped that the information would include the remote host and port.

Comment: *"the OS should retain some information."* - why should it? It doesn't need these information.